# Why will PHP not show all JSON data in file (or see it when referensed using key)

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON data:

```
 { "angus.seya@yourmum.com69420666777Google Pixel XL": [
[
  "Screen Shot 2019-08-08 at 6.08.09 pm.png"
],
null,
"Google Pixel XL",
"This is a pixel XL, glass is fine, LCD brocken and mainboard broke.",
0,
[
  [
    "There are no messages."
  ],
  [
    "Logan Paul - Angus",
    "Logan - Hi, I want a frog mask",
    "Angus - Sorry, I this is about the pixel not frog mask."
  ]
] ]}
```

Pretty image version here:

[image]

I want to echo the 5th element to screen, (just a print_r which will show sub arrays too for the moment). However, my code (below) outputs this:

```
//OUTPUT: //DONT WORRY ABOUT ANYTHING UNTIL !ISSUE COMMENT!
//Array ( [0] => There are no messages. ) 

//Code: 
<?php
$id =  $_POST['id']; //user@domain69420666777add_name
$reply =  $_POST['reply'];

$replys = explode("69420666777",$id);
$name = explode("@", $replys[0]);
$name = ($name[0]);

$craft = $name . " - " . $reply;
#echo $craft;
```

**// JSON--   !!!!ISSUE FROM HERE ON! VVV**

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('../adds.json');
$id = $_GET['add'];
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true); echo "<br>";
print_r($data[$id][5])




 ?>
```

Thanks for any help. I hope I explained it well enough.

Answer (score 0):

this was my fault:
Issue was this line

```
$id = $_GET['add'];
```

was overwriting this line before it.

```
$id =  $_POST['id'];
```

There is no $_GET data. I forgot I pasted that in from my previous code.
Sorry.